# Как выполнять 200 000 запросов mysql insert в сутки?

Tags: mysql

Есть необходимость выполнять 200 000 запросов mysql insert в сутки. Сейчас на это уходит около 5 часов. Скрипт находится на VPS. Система ежедневно загружает строки из CSV. Возможно ли ускорить процесс?

Comment: В ответах уже попытались наванговать и нателепатить, но добавить подробностей в вопрос всё равно крайне желательно

Answer (score 15):

Зависит от того, как именно происходит процесс загрузки, однако обычно проблема медленной вставки связана с индексами, констрейнтами и foreign key на таблицах. Базе нужно делать дополнительные проверки для соблюдения всех этих ограничений. Также может помочь отключение автокоммита (в случае с InnoDB), который будет писать в бинлог после каждого инсерта чтобы обеспечить сохранность данных.

Общие рекомендации можно найти вот тут (InnoDB): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

и вот тут (MyISAM): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html

Answer (score 12):

Честно говоря, на Ваш вопрос можно ответить только тыкая пальцем в небо, потому что вы по сути не написали ничего про структуру вашей базы и используемое железо (ресурсы).

С помощью нехитрой математики можно понять, что скорость выполнения одного запроса на INSERT у вас 90мс, или примерно 11 запросов на INSERT в секунду. Вообще INSERT очень быстрая операция и может выполняться в среднем 0.2-1.0 мс, но не в вашем случае...

Давайте разберем, на что тратиться время при INSERT?

- Подключение (или использование существующего соединения)
- Посылка запроса на сервер
- Синтаксический анализ запроса
- Проверка ключей (если они есть)
- Вставка записи
- Вставка индексов
- Закрытие

Так в чем же у Вас могут быть проблемы

**1. Слабое аппаратное обеспечение или ошибки в нем**

Если не вникать в структуру вашей базы данных, используемый движок, и т.д. можно сказать, что у вас слабое аппаратное обеспечение, и если Вы хотите ускорить операцию вставки вам нужен более мощный процессор, большее кол-во оперативной памяти и SSD диск который имеет в разы большее IOPS. А возможно, раз это VPS, диск на который осуществляется запись просто перегружен, проведите benchmark вашего железа в момент **INSERT**. Также может быть сильная фрагментация на диске.

**2. Неправильно настроенная конфигурация базы данных**

Далее, если с этим проблем нет, то значит у Вас плохо настроена конфигурация MySQL. Обычно камнями преткновения в innoDB становятся следующие настройки

- innodb_log_file_size
- innodb_buffer_pool_size
- innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit
- innodb_flush_method
- log_bin and sync_binlog
- innodb_buffer_pool_instances
- innodb_write_io_threads

Например innodb_log_file_size, хорошо влияет на производительность, но по умолчанию его размер очень маленький.

А если данные можно перезапросить, то совсем необязательно напрягать диск постоянным сбросом данных, поэтому можно использовать другое значение innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit (1 - безопаснее, 2 - быстрее)

> innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit — жалуетесь, что InnoDB работает в 100
>   раз медленнее MyISAM? Вероятно, Вы забыли про настройку
>   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit. Значение по умолчанию «1» означает,
>   что каждая UPDATE-транзакция (или аналогичная команда вне транзакции)
>   должна сбрасывать буфер на диск, что достаточно ресурсоёмко.
>   Большинство приложений, в особенности ранее использовавшие таблицы
>   MyISAM, будут хорошо работать со значением «2» (т.е. «не сбрасывать
>   буфер на диск, только в кэш ОС»). Лог, однако, всё равно будет
>   сбрасываться на диск каждые 1-2 секунды, поэтому в случае аварии Вы
>   потеряете максимум 1-2 секунды обновлений. Значение «0» повысит
>   производительность, но Вы рискуете потерять данные даже при аварийной
>   остановке mySQL-сервера, в то время как при установке значение
>   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit в «2» Вы потеряете данные только при
>   аварии всей операционной системы.

**3. Сложная архитектура базы данных или большая таблица**

Возможно у Вас огромная таблица и большое кол-во индексов или внешних ключей, из-за которых при INSERT проверяется большое кол-во условий и обновляются файлы индексов. Удалите все ненужные индексы. Возможно у Вас индексы, которые просто не помещается в память и это означает, что InnoDB может при вставке подтягивает с диска данные постранично в зависимости от записи **и это очень медленно.**

Возможно при больших обьемах данных Вам поможет партицирование.

Сложная и большая архитектура требует больших ресурсов для быстрой работы.

**4. Неправильное использование конструкций для вставки данных**

Выполняете вставку по одному INSERT, да еще без транзакций и выполняется медленно? А чего вы хотели? Думали будет быстро? Нет, большое кол-во данных нужно вставлять через большой INSERT запрос или LOAD DATA INFILE. При сбрасывании на диск каждой операции, последовательные INSERT будут выполняться очень медленно. Ускорить INSERT также можно через какой-нибудь Handlersocket, это не даст ощутимого прироста, но уберет дополнительные расходы на анализ запроса.

Перечислил основные причины. Без подробной информации о вашем сервере, конфигурации и архитектуры больше не знаю, что еще сказать.

**В любом случае нужно тестировать изменения конфигурации и архитектуры, вы можете увеличить скорость вставки, но замедлить скорость поиска.**

Answer (score 11):

Подозреваю, что вы вставляете записи по одной.
Более быстрый способ — вставлять по много записей в одном insert

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES (row11, row21), 
(row21, row22), ... (row1n, row2n);
```

Также хорошо отдельно сформировать sql файл, который затем выполнить [используя souce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html).